# Has a tennis player ever hit a shot behind the umpire's chair that landed inbounds in a singles match?

Tags: tennis, history

There have been many [tennis shots that went around the net post](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G5oTBIxbBOA).

But has any tennis player ever hit a shot that went *behind* the umpire's chair and still landed inbounds in a singles match? There are some tennis courts that have enough space where this is theoretically possible:

[image]

I already found that it happened in a doubles match at the college level, when [Gregor Ramskogler](https://www.marca.com/en/more-sports/2020/03/11/5e692ba8268e3e262a8b45cb.html) did it for Mississippi State against Tennessee on or about March 8, 2020.